# CSS is getting break in iOS 10 iPhone 6/7 mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, ios10

Media viewport user-scalable=no" is not supporting with position: fixed style.

Comment: Share some code, or a working fiddle.

Comment: I am using this reference http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/qg44N

Comment: Could you add relevant code snippets to your question and show/describe your issues in detail (errors, etc)?